# symfony + user bundle: which is the "layout" template?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I need to change the aspect of email that Symfony (FOS USerBundle) sends when user registering into my site via API. Into the "register function" I have this line:

`$this->get('fos_user.mailer')->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);`

The email is send, but which is the template that I need to change ? For test I have insert a file name string in all these files:

- `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/Registration/confirmed.html.twig`
- `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig`
- `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/Registration/check_email.html.twig`
- `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/Registration/email.txt.twig`

but the email that arrive does not contain my changes.

Where is my error ?

Answer (score 1):

Create this tree in app and put what you want to send in `email.txt.twig`

[image]